# Typeahead.js - Cannot read property of 'isArray' of undefined

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js

I am trying to implement the `typeahead.js` autocomplete/search in an ASP MVC view but, in Chrome's Console, when the page loads I am receiving the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isArray' of undefined ...  typeahead.js:26
```

This is the section of code in the typeahead.js file it is referring to

```
    isString: function(obj) {
        return typeof obj === "string";
    },
    isNumber: function(obj) {
        return typeof obj === "number";
    },
    isArray: $.isArray, <-UncaughtTypeError: Cannor read property of 'isArray' of undefined
    isFunction: $.isFunction,
    isObject: $.isPlainObject,
    isUndefined: function(obj) {
        return typeof obj === "undefined";
    },
```

Here is the `typeahead` code along with the declarations I am using.

```
<script src="http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.typeahead').typeahead({
            source: function (term, process) {
                var url = '@Url.Content("~/Home/GetNames")';

                return $.getJSON(url, { term: term }, function (data) {
                    return process(data);
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And here is the input element being used for the search

```
            <form class="navbar-search pull-left">  
              <input type="text" value="" id="typeahead" data-provide="typeahead" class="search-query" /> @*placeholder=" Agent search" />*@  
            </form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Invert the `typehead` and `jquery` script definitions as more than obviously the first depends on the second:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```